# Is there a document about handling error of google calendar API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm wondering if there is a web page from Google to describe how to handling errors of google calendar API. Driver has one page at https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors . I haven't found a similar page by google search. Please let me know if there is one page for that.

Cheers!

Comment: I have the same question.  The answer below doesn't work for me.  The only exception class shown there is GoogleApiRequestException, and when I use it, it cannot be found.  I'm doing something wrong, and a calendar specific example would sure be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a little too late for this but there is one for V3 now:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same example code of Google Drive API with your application using Google Calendar. For example, to return an error of a resource not found (error 404) or a service that cannot be executed, you can do the following:

```
  <?php

  try { 
    $service->events->delete($calendar, $id, array('sendNotifications' => true)); 
    return true; 
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) { 
    print $e->getCode(); 
    //return false; 
    // or display the error message with $e->getMessage()
  }

  ?>
```

So, in the other function that tries to use this google service you can handle this error.